# http request header text/plain flutter

Tags: flutter, http, http-headers

How to http request with header text/plain instead of application/json. Is it possible? I have tried a few methods not been able to request them correctly. In postman, It is working.

Code :

```
Map<String, dynamic> data = {"RequestdatagoeshereasObject"};

 var uri = Uri.parse("MyURLgoeshere");


    final response = await http.post( uri, body: data,headers: { "Content-Type":  "text/plain",
    "Accept":  "*/*"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by doing this

```
request.headers.set('Content-type', 'text/plain');
```